# PHP YII 2 - How to sort a data in from A-Z or Z-A?

Tags: php, sorting, yii2

i want to `SORT` my data in gridview based on alphabet, my code is work if sort by ID when ID contains number, e.g 1-100 or 100-1.
How to `sort` from A-Z or Z-A? is it possible to custom `Yii2 sort`?

i have a code in controller :

```
public function actionItemreport()
{
    $modelFunctions = new functions;
    $modelFunctions->checkingUser( $this, Yii::$app->controller->id, Yii::$app->controller->action->id );
    
    $this->transfield = array( 'icitem' => $modelFunctions->getFieldTranslationTable( 'icitem' ), 'iclink' => $modelFunctions->getFieldTranslationTable( 'iclink' ) );
    
    $arrDays = array( '0' => $this->arrtrans[134], '1' => $this->arrtrans[135], '2' => $this->arrtrans[136], '3' => $this->arrtrans[137], '4' => $this->arrtrans[138], '5' => $this->arrtrans[139], '6' => $this->arrtrans[140] );  
    $arrSchedule = $this->getItemReportScheduler();
    
    $ftpSql = "SELECT * FROM icenvinit";
    $a_icenvinit = Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $ftpSql )->queryOne();
    
    if( $a_icenvinit['hostaddr1'] != "" )
    {
        $arr_ftp['FTP1'] = $this->arrtrans[141];
    }
    
    if( $a_icenvinit['hostaddr2'] != "" )
    {
        $arr_ftp['FTP2'] = $this->arrtrans[142];
    }
    
    switch ( intval($arrSchedule['type']) )
    {
        case 1 :    $listSchedule = "[ " . $this->arrtrans[143] . " ] : {$arrSchedule['hour']}:{$arrSchedule['minute']}";
                    break;
        case 2 :    $days = $arrDays[$arrSchedule['day']];
                    $listSchedule = "[ " . $this->arrtrans[144] . " ] : {$days} {$arrSchedule['hour']}:{$arrSchedule['minute']}";
                    break;
        case 3 :    $date = $arrSchedule['date'];
                    $listSchedule = "[ " . $this->arrtrans[145] . " ] : {$date} {$arrSchedule['hour']}:{$arrSchedule['minute']}";
                    break;
        case 4 :    $listSchedule = "[ " . $this->arrtrans[146] . " ] : Every {$arrSchedule['interval']} Hour(s)";
                    break;  
        default :   $listSchedule = $this->arrtrans[147];
                    $listTarget = "";
                    break;
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM icdbval";

    $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand( "select count(1) from icdbval" )->queryScalar();

    
    $arrsort['attributes'] = array( 'id' => array( 'label' => $this->arrtrans[148] ) );
    $arrsort['attributes'] += array( 'orgfield' => array( 'label' => $this->arrtrans[149] ) ); //, 'asc' => array('orgfield' => SORT_ASC)
    $arrsort['attributes'] += array( 'status' => array( 'label' => $this->arrtrans[91] ) );
    $arrsort['defaultOrder'] = array( 'id' => SORT_ASC );
    
    $sort = $arrsort;

    $a = 0;
    $arrview = array();

    $arrview[$a]['attribute'] = 'id';
    $arrview[$a]['label'] = $this->arrtrans[148];
    $arrview[$a]['encodeLabel'] = false;
    $arrview[$a++]['value'] = function ( $data )
    {
        return $data['id'];
    };
        
    $arrview[$a]['attribute'] = 'orgfield';
    $arrview[$a]['label'] = $this->arrtrans[149];
    $arrview[$a]['encodeLabel'] = false;
    $arrview[$a++]['value'] = function ( $data )
    {
        return $this->get_trans_field( $data['orgfield'] );
    };
    
    $arrview[$a]['attribute'] = 'status';
    $arrview[$a]['label'] = $this->arrtrans[91];
    $arrview[$a]['encodeLabel'] = false;
    $arrview[$a]['format'] = 'raw';
    $arrview[$a++]['value'] = function ( $data )
    {
        if( $data['status'] == "0" )
        {
            $select0 = "selected";
            $select1 = "";
            
        }
        else
        {
            $select1 = "selected";
            $select0 = "";      
        }
        
        $id = $data['id'];
        
        $ni = $this->arrtrans[150];
        $in = $this->arrtrans[151];
        
        $html = <<< "SCRIPT"
            <select class="_statusselect" theval="$id">
                <option value="0" $select0>$ni</option>
                <option value="1" $select1>$in</option>
            </select>
SCRIPT;
        // return $data['status'];
        return $html;
    };
    
    $columnview = $arrview;

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $sql,
        'totalCount' => $count,
        'sort' => $sort,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => Yii::$app->db->createCommand( "SELECT rowpage from icenvinit" )->queryScalar(),
        ],
    ]);
    
    return $this->render( 'itemreport', ['error' => $error, 'success' => $success, 'columnview' => $columnview, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'sql' => $sql, 'count' => $count, 'listSchedule' => $listSchedule, 'arr_ftp' => $arr_ftp] );
}
```

and in a view :

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'item-report', 'timeout' => false]) ?>
        <?
            $js = <<< 'SCRIPT'
                function changestatus( obj )
                {
                    $( '#successalert' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                    $( '#erroralert' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                    $.ajax({
                        type     :'POST',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data : ({xval: obj.val(), id: obj.attr( 'theval' )}),
                        url  : 'updateitemreport',
                        success  : function( response )
                        {
                            if( response.error )
                            {
                                // $( '#successalert' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                                // $( '#erroralert' ).html( response.html );
                                // $( '#erroralert' ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // $( '#erroralert' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                                // $( '#successalert' ).html( response.html );
                                // $( '#successalert' ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                
                $( '._statusselect' ).change( function() {
                    changestatus( $( this ) );
                });
SCRIPT;

$this->registerJs( $js, yii\web\View::POS_READY );
?>
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $columnview,
        ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add asc and desc in the options of the attribute  eg in your `orgfield` attribute;

```
.....
$arrsort['attributes'] = array( 'id' => array( 'label' => $this->arrtrans[148] ) );
$arrsort['attributes'] += array( 
        'orgfield' => array( 'label' => $this->arrtrans[149], 
                             'asc' => array('orgfield' => SORT_ASC),
                             'desc' => array('orgfield' => SORT_DESC),
                              ) ); 

.....
```

Comment: what's happen when  clicking on the header label in grid view  ?